# Why doesn't the values change if I multiply by $\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$?

Tags: trigonometry, inequality

So my trig professor solved the problem below as follows:

$\sin x - \cos x > 0$

Multiplying by $\frac{{\sqrt{2}}}{2}$:

$(\sin x)\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} - (\cos x) \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}>0$

$\sin x\cos\frac{\pi }{4} - \cos x \sin\frac{\pi }{4}>0$

$\sin\left ( x - \frac{\pi}{4} \right ) > 0$

$\frac{\pi}{4}+2k\pi\leq x\leq \frac{5\pi}{4}+2k\pi$

What I don't understand is how multiplying the inequality by $\frac{{\sqrt{2}}}{2}$ "doesn't change the value of the inequality" as my professor said. Am I missing something here?

Comment: Your notation is confusing. You can multiply an inequality by a positive quantity without changing the inequality. Don't try it with a negative quantity, though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you are confused. If $a>b$ then the equality doesn't change even if we multiply both sides by an positive integer $k$.

So it would be $$ ka>kb $$

However if we multiply both sides by a negative integer say l then inequality becomes $$ la<lb $$

Thus multiplying by positive integer doesn't changes the inequality but positive integer does. Multiplying both sides by $0$ will make the equality equal.

Comment: Oh well. Guess I didn't really think this through. Thanks for the quick answer.

Comment: @RedonQerimi Good to know it helped. If it helped you the most then you can click click the white button to make to green. It will give you +2 reputation and +15 to me. Let me tell you that accepting my answer is not important but I guess you should try to accept one of all answers if your query has been solved

Answer (score 1):

Just like how if $x=y$, then $a\cdot x=a\cdot y$, you can do the same for inequalities. *However*, if $a<0$, then you have to flip the direction of the inequality. And you can't multiply by $a=0$ if you're using $>$ or $<$, because $0>0$ is false.